# ARC error while stubbing [CLLocationManager authorizationStatus] using OCMock in Xcode9.1

Tags: objective-c, ocmock, xcode9.1

I am using OCMock to stub `[CLLocationManager authorizationStatus]` for unit test cases. Seems like *Xcode9.1* is getting confused with method name as same methods are present in other classes like `CMPedometer` & `CMAltimeter`. It's not hapenning with *Xcode8.3* though.
[Click Here to see the Screenshot for Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PLlBc.png)

Answer (score 0):

Mocks are written so that they can be used with any class and because Objective-C doesn't have generics they can't declare the correct return type for a specific class. Instead, they always use `id`.

In your case, adding a cast as follows should fix the issue.

```
[(CLLocationManager)[[self.mockedApplication stub] andReturnValue: ... ] 
    authorizationStatus];
```

PS: In future, please post the full code as text, too, not just a screenshot.

Comment: Tried this, getting error "No visible @ interface for 'CLLocationManager' declares the selector "

Comment: The method is declared in `CLLocationManager.h`, the header file for the class. You have to import that, directly or indirectly.

Comment: I imported `CLLocationManager.h` . I tried using `(CLLocationManager *)` and was getting `No visible interface` error. With `(CLLocationManager)` I am getting `Used type 'CLLocationManager' where arithmetic or pointer type is` @ErikDoernenburg